# How to define a ElementCollection of an Embedded type which contains @OneToMany relation in JPA 2.0

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

> Hi All,
>
> I am new to JPA. I am facing an issue in below scenario;
>
> I have an embeddable class ContactInformation as mention below;

```
@Embeddable public class ContactInformation {
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Phone> phoneList;
    @Embedded
    private Address address;
......
}
```

> > I have another entity class Employee as shown below;

```
   @Entity

   @IdClass(EmployeeId.class)

   public class Employee implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   private String id;

   @Id
   private String name;

   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name = "employee_interests") 
   private Set<String> interests;
//COMPILE TIME ERROR LINE BELOW
   @ElementCollection
   private Set<ContractInformation> info;

    ...
    }
```

> > In above case, I am getting compile time error in above mention line as **"Mapping contains an embeddable "main.ContractInformation" with a prohibited mapping "phoneList", embeddables in element collections may only contain many-to-one or one-to-one mappings which must be on the "owning" side of the relationship and must not use join table"**

Can you please help me how we can correct this?

Thanks for your help in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, an embeddable cannot use a mapping that requires a foreign key to point at the embeddable, such as a OneToMany or ManyToMany.  Thisis because the embeddable doesn't have a primary key for the foreign keys required by the mappings to point to.  Make your embeddable a full entity instead.

Comment: Or make it so that an amployee will only have one contact info.  I'm not sure why there would be multiple phones associated to a contactinfo yet only one address.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this a limitation of JPA that an Embeddable class can't have OneToMany or ManyToMany relation if that embedded class is part of an ElementCollection of an entity class?        The example above is  just for practice.

Comment: Yes, based on how databases work.  Embeddables don't have their own identity, so they cannot be uniquely identified. 1:M and M:M require the target side knowing what object they point to - a back reference is stored in the database.  But since nothing uniquely identifies your ContractInformation objects, they can't be distinguished from one another, so there is no way to tell which ContractInformation a particular Phone belongs to.